# how to display xml xslt code using google chrome or firefox in linux mint 20?

Tags: xml, xslt

i tried to display result of my .xml file that i styled using .xslt  in firefox and google chrome
and  i got nothing .

I'm using Linux Mint 20 Ulyana Xfce

my .xml file:

```
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="exemple1.xsl"?>
    <node>helo World</node>
```

my .xsl file :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html> 
            <body>
                <h1><xsl:value-of select="node"/></h1>
                
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Where do you load the XML from, over the local file system or over HTTP(S)? Only the latter continues to work in those browsers.

Comment: i loaded it from locale file sir. I'm new to xml so i just write in locale file and test using web browser

Comment: Google Chrome hasn't supported loading XSLT referenced in XML loaded from the local file system for many years, Firefox also has discontinued that feature more than a year ago. Thus, if you want to use `<?xml-stylesheet?>` with those browsers, you need to load over HTTP(S) e.g. localhost.

Comment: ok sir. Now i understand you, thank you very much !